# PL/SQL iterate all schemas and run the same query on all of them

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have various Oracle databases, eg ONE.db TWO.db THIRD.db etc and I want to run a SELECT which runs successfully on ONE.db, for example, `SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS` etc. and then get the results per database. How can I do this using PL/SQL? (no db links or tools etc.)

Comment: You can't do queries across database in Oracle, you always need to (re-)connect to send a query to a different database so this won't be possible in a single PL/SQL program. Or are you actually talking about schemas (i.e. users)

Comment: Without DB links this is impossible... Are you sure about your conditions?

Comment: "ONE.db TWO.db THIRD.db" seems to imply schemas rather than databases.

Comment: You should read a little bit about Oracle [schema](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Schema) and [instance](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/startup.htm).Just to clear up some confusions. Happy reading!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about schemas, not separate database instances, and assuming the structure of all the CUSTOMERS tables are exactly identical (including column order), you could log in as a user that has SELECT access to all of the tables, then:

```
SELECT 'ONE' owner, c.* FROM one.customers c
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TWO' owner, c.* FROM two.customers c
UNION ALL
SELECT 'THIRD' owner, c.* FROM third.customers c
;
```

Whether you need the first column "owner" or not is up to you.

If you want to generate the above statement at runtime with PL/SQL, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE
  qry VARCHAR2(32767);
  rc sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT owner, table_name
            FROM all_tables
            WHERE table_name = 'CUSTOMERS') LOOP
    IF qry IS NOT NULL THEN
      qry := qry || ' UNION ALL ';
    END IF;
    qry := qry || 'SELECT '''
               || r.owner
               || ''' owner, c.* FROM '
               || r.owner
               || '.customers c';
  END LOOP;
  OPEN rc FOR qry;
  -- fetch from the ref cursor and do whatever you want with the records
END;
```